# Error: fetching abi for eosio: deadline exceeded by xx us

Tags: transactions, eosjs, abi, execution-time

When launching a transaction like:

```
await eosioApi.transact({
    actions: [
        {
            account: "eosio",
            name: 'newaccount',
            authorization: [{
                actor: "eosio",
                permission: 'active',
            }],
            data: {
                creator: "eosio",
                name: "mynewaccount",
                owner: {
                    threshold: 1,
                    keys: [{
                        key: publicKey,
                        weight: 1
                    }],
                    accounts: [],
                    waits: []
                },
                active: {
                    threshold: 1,
                    keys: [{
                        key: publicKey,
                        weight: 1
                    }],
                    accounts: [],
                    waits: []
                },
            },
        }
    ]
},
{
    blocksBehind: 3,
    expireSeconds: 30,
});
```

I get the following error

```
(node:17020) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: fetching abi for eosio: deadline 2020-02-26T14:23:16.796 exceeded by 87us 
at new RpcError (/home/jochen/eos/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-rpcerror.js:26:28)
at JsonRpc.<anonymous> (/home/jochen/eos/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-jsonrpc.js:118:35)
at step (/home/jochen/eos/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-jsonrpc.js:36:23)
at Object.next (/home/jochen/eos/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-jsonrpc.js:17:53)
at fulfilled (/home/jochen/eos/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-jsonrpc.js:8:58)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

The server itself says:

```
error 2020-02-26T14:40:03.271 http-1    http_plugin.cpp:238           handle_exception     ] Internal Service error, http: 2 timeout_exception: deadline 2020-02-26T14:40:03.270 exceeded by 933us 
deadline 2020-02-26T14:40:03.270 exceeded by 933us 
    {"d":"2020-02-26T14:40:03.270","t":933}
    http-1  json.cpp:499 escape_string
```

Any idea what is the reasin for this? What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: I am also getting this error. My laptop performance is pretty high, so not sure what to do here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by starting nodeos while setting

> --abi-serializer-max-time-ms

to 50000 or so.

I'm not sure if there's such an option in eos-js but if you get the error using cleos, you can additionally start keosd while setting

> --http-max-response-time-ms=

to 1000 or so.

Answer (score 0):

It was a performance issue on my computer. At the moment the issue was solved the error vanished.